# Spring Web mvc - Failed to instantiate NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, noclassdeffounderror

I've got a problem with my spring/servlet project,
each time I try to run the server, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDaoBd' defined in file [/home/excess/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/gouvlad/WEB-INF/classes/dao/impl/PersonDaoBd.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.impl.PersonDaoBd]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources
```

Here are my classes:

PersonDaoBd.java

```
package dao.impl;
/* some imports */
...
@Service
public class PersonDaoBd implements IPersonDao {

    private String driverName = Resources.getString("KeyDriverName");
    private String url        = Resources.getString("KeyUrl");
    private String user       = Resources.getString("KeyUser"); 
    private String password   = Resources.getString("KeyPassword");
    private Connection connection;

    @Autowired
    private IPersonFactory personFactory;

    @Autowired
    private IGroupFactory groupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor of the PersonDaoBd class
     * 
     * @throws SQLException if the connection failed
     */
    public PersonDaoBd() throws SQLException{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }
    ...
```

Resources.java

```
package dao.impl;

import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Resources {
    private static String BUNDLE_NAME = "dao.impl.messages";

    private static ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    public Resources() {
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the beginning of my controller:

```
package web;

/* skipped some imports...*/

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/annuaire")
public class AnnuaireController {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private IPersonDao dao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/liste", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //System.out.println(dao);
        if (!Utils.isConnected(request.getSession())){
            logger.info("Returning connexion view");
            return new ModelAndView("connexion");
        }
        return new ModelAndView("annuaire");

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/style.css", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleRequestStyle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        return new ModelAndView("style");

    }    

}
```

Here are my xml files:

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao.impl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="bean" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="bean.impl" />

    <bean name="personFactory" class="bean.Person" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean name="IPersonFactory" class="bean.impl.PersonFactory">
        <lookup-method bean="personFactory" name="getPerson" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="groupFactory" class="bean.Group" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean name="IGroupFactory" class="bean.impl.GroupFactory">
        <lookup-method bean="groupFactory" name="getGroup" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

and finally, springapp-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="web" />
<context:component-scan base-package="dao.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

I'm a beginner in Spring, I'm on this problem since yesterday and I cannot figure out what is wrong. It seems that Spring cannot instantiate the personDaoBd object because it doesn't find the Resources class. However, these classes are in the same package. 
Moreover, I have no problem with this test class which is not a bean:

```
package dao.impl;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/spring.xml")
public class PersonDaoBdTest {

    @Autowired
    IPersonDao dao;

    ...
```

In this case, the PersonDaoBd object is well instantiated. I've no problem to run tests.

If someone has an idea about that, I would be grateful !

Edit: Here is the complete StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDaoBd' defined in file [/home/excess/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/gouvlad/WEB-INF/classes/dao/impl/PersonDaoBd.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.impl.PersonDaoBd]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4138)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.impl.PersonDaoBd]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources
    at dao.impl.PersonDaoBd.<init>(PersonDaoBd.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dao.impl.Resources
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 39 more

déc. 12, 2016 1:56:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDaoBd' defined in file [/home/excess/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/gouvlad/WEB-INF/classes/dao/impl/PersonDaoBd.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.impl.PersonDaoBd]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4138)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.impl.PersonDaoBd]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources
    at dao.impl.PersonDaoBd.<init>(PersonDaoBd.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dao.impl.Resources
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 39 more

déc. 12, 2016 1:56:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [springapp] in web application [/gouvlad] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dao.impl.Resources
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at dao.impl.PersonDaoBd.<init>(PersonDaoBd.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4138)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr.univ-amu</groupId>
  <artifactId>gouvlad</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gouvlad Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>gouvlad</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Main problem is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/Resources`

Comment: Add more informations like complete stacktrace and the related code

Comment: Seems like you are running tomcat using eclipse. Can you ensure if `Resources.class` is present on `/home/excess/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/gouvlad/WEB-INF/classes/dao/impl` this path (the path from which your code is being served)?

Comment: Indeed, you're right. And no ! Resources.class is not present in this repertory. But the other files are in. Why ? Isn't it put there during compilation ?

Comment: Are you using any build tool, like Maven?

Comment: It seems dao.impl.Resources.class is loaded some where else in your super class loader and it fails to load(may be it has parameter constructor or apis is not same).Can you check by changing your package name some thing like dao.impl.ResourcesOne ?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm editing my initial post to display the pom.xml

Comment: If I change my package name, I get this error: ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dao.impl.PersonDaoBd]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dao/impl/resourcesOne/Resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution
I had the same package name in two different repertories:
- dao.impl in src/main/java
- dao.impl in src/test/java

After compilation, it seems that the classes located in src/test/java were not moved to the .class folder. I still don't know why.
My Resources class was located in this folder. I just moved it to src/main/java and it solved the problem.

Comment: its maven behaviour .It will create two packages src/test/java and src/main/java.All test cases you can create in test folder.It won't impact main classes.